# Yandex Map Kit смена языка

Tags: яндекс-карты, yandexmapkit

Как возможно сменить язык на карте ? Проблема в том что даже при переключении языка всего приложения, язык на картах не меняется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ от Яндекс (22.02.17) ."Дело в том, что в yandexmapkit, доступном пользователю, есть доступ только к картам на русском языке. Поэтому, к сожалению, локализовать карты не получится."